# Angular 6 services, HTTPClient

Tags: angular-services, angular-httpclient, angular6

I am new to Angular 5 and I am currently trying to display data from a database to a view. But I am definitely doing something wrong since the view is just getting [object object]. I would like some help in what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

**Service**[image: The service to use]

**Component using the service**
[image]

**The Component's HTML**
[image]

**The View**

[image]

Comment: user is a object, to display the user object as is change {{user}} to {{user | json}}. To display an property from the object add: {{user._id}}

Answer (score 4):

To display the students (not like JSON) , you need to call  object.property , in your case `user.first_name, user.last_name, user.user_type`.
Your component HTML :

```
<h1>CDM Student</h1>
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   {{user.first_name}}  {{user.last_name}}
</div>code here
```

Also in your API  http://localhost:3000/api/users , you shouldn't return the PASSWORD in the JSON (be very careful with this kind of information)

Answer (score 3):

your Code is ok . just add angular json pipe.
Have you seen https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

The Component's HTML

```
<h1>CDM Student</h1>
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
   {{user | json}}
</div>code here
```

maybe it's helpful for you . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your case user is an object, 
 1. if you want to display an object then use JSON pipe.

```
   {{user | json}}
```

2. If you want to display sub property of an object then use

```
{{user.propertyName}}
```

for example :

```
{{user.firstName}}
```